# Webpack to build HTML page based on different HTML files

Tags: html, webpack

I have a HTML footer which it is exactly the same in 20 pages. Nothing dynamic about it, just static HTML.

I am looking to do something like the following example with Webpack:

**/src/templates/myfotter.hml**

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>CONTACT</h3>
                <p>
                    bla, bla, bla
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**/src/views/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <myfotter></myfotter>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/dist/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>contact</h3>
                    <p>
                        bla, bla, bla
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is any way to do that with Webpack?

Comment: It does. Thank you very much.